# How do I run a large number of blocking operations in a performant way?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, .net-4.7.2

I want to execute a library method that does a blocking I/O operation many times (up to 67840 calls). The library does not provide an async version of the method.

Since in most cases the call just waits for a timeout, I want to run multiple calls in parallel. My method is async, therefore it would be good if I could `await` the result.

Since the `ThreadPool` should not be used for blocking operations, I would like to do the following:

- Start a number of threads (e.g. 1024)
- Run the blocking calls on these threads
- `await` the completion (e. g. via `TaskCompletionSource`) and process the result of each call in normal Tasks on the `TheadPool`

Are there existing classes in .NET with which I could achive something like this? I am aware of `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, but as far as I can see this would create a new thread for each call.

Comment: I hate to tell you, but... "Since the call mostly waits for the I/O operation to complete, I want to run multiple calls in parallel."... running multiple operations in parallel WILL NOT INCREASE THE AVAILABLE IO. This is exactly a scenario where parallel calls do NOT work to make things faster, unless i.e. you call an API where the time DOES scale parallel (as another call uses i.e. another thread/system on the backend). But if you are IO bound, parallelism may actually make things SLOWER.

Comment: I clarified the question: Most calls do to the method just time out, therefore I am not limited by network bandwidth.

Comment: I am sorry, but the fact that you get timeouts ALREADY points to an IO overload. Throwing MORE IO to the problem does not look like it is even remotely a smart idea.

Comment: You could try to implement a pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline

Comment: OK, I should have been move specific: I am scanning a network. Most of the time there is not server on the other side, therefore all the blocking operation does is wait for an answer.

Comment: I doubt framework has anything for this, because it's not intended usage. For IO you use non blocking IO calls, for CPU work you won't need so many threads. I mean in your case you might have no choice but it would be strange for framework to provide solution for this situation.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) at this point. What are you trying to achieve with scanning thousands of computers.

Comment: @TomTom imagine you need to perform 10 web requests but for whatever reason you can't use asynchronous IO. Then doing it in parallel will certainly be faster than making those requests one after another.

Comment: Sorry, but the question talks of IO limitations. 10 web requests to a (scalable) API are not having IO limitations. Network scans are not IO bound by design (there is plenty of bandwidth, and ping/icmp packets are extremely small), so the question I commented on is TOTALLY OFF in the description, simple like that.

Comment: When you say *I want to execute a library method that does a blocking I/O operation many times (up to 67840 calls)* - is it the library that is doing 67000 calls, or you?

Comment: @CaiusJard I am.

Comment: Is this operation performed only once, or it can be performed multiple times during the lifetime of the process? In the second case it might make sense to actually use the `ThreadPool` after all. You'll just need to configure the `ThreadPool` for the specific usage: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1024, 1024);`, and then use the parallel library of your choice (`Parallel.ForEach`, PLINQ, TPL Dataflow etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> blocking I/O operation... The library does not provide an async version of the method.

Just from this, you know you won't end up with an "ideal" solution. Ideally, I/O is performed asynchronously. In fact, on Windows, *all* I/O *is* performed asynchronously at the OS level, with each synchronous API call just blocking the current thread until that asynchronous operation completes.

So, the first thing you should accept is that you'll need to bend the rules a little.

> Since in most cases the call just waits for a timeout, I want to run multiple calls in parallel.

Yes. Parallelism is an appropriate solution. If it were possible to do the I/O asynchronously, then parallelism would *not* be the appropriate solution, but since the I/O is blocking (and you have no control over that), then parallelism is the best solution you're left with.

> My method is async, therefore it would be good if I could await the result.

This doesn't necessarily follow. It's acceptable for asynchronous methods to be partially blocking, as long as that's clearly documented. The asynchronous signature (i.e., "returns a `Task`" and has an `*Async` suffix) implies that the method *may* be asynchronous, not that it *must* be asynchronous.

Personally, [I prefer not to do thread offloading in my logic methods, and only do it when *calling* them from the UI layer](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) (link to my blog).

> Since the ThreadPool should not be used for blocking operations

Well, this is one of those rules you can consider bending. The thread pool does work just fine with blocking operations, and in fact it's my first suggested solution.

> Start a number of threads (e.g. 1024)... Run the blocking calls on these threads

If you toss out the "I want my own threads" part and just use the thread pool, then the answer is quite simple: `Parallel` or PLINQ would work quite nicely. You can set a maximum level of parallelism for both of these approaches, and you can set a larger than normal minimum thread count on the thread pool to scale up the number of threads more quickly if you want.

This does toss a lot of blocking work on the thread pool, which is generally not recommended but can work in some scenarios. Specifically, client applications like console apps or GUI apps would work fine with this. If this is in a web app, though, then you would not want to fill up the thread pool with blocking calls. In that case, I'd actually recommend splitting up the scanning to a separate app using a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) (link to my blog).

> await the completion (e. g. via TaskCompletionSource) and process the result of each call in normal Tasks on the TheadPool

If you want to do the parallel work on a separate thread, then you can wrap it in `await Task.Run(...)`; mucking around with TCS isn't necessary.